# How to Register and handle a UserControl programmatically from code behind?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, code-behind

I want to Register (or reference) and handle a UserControl programmatically from code behind. I googled a lot, but didn't find a useful solution for registering or referencing a UserControl.

EDIT:

I have done as follow:

ASPX Page:

```
<%@ Reference Control="~/ucContents.ascx" %>
```

ASPX page code behind:

```
    Control Contents1 = null;
    try
    {
        Contents1 = LoadControl("~/ucContents.ascx");
        if (Contents1 != null)
        {
           ((ucContents)Contents1).CatID = Request.QueryString["catid"];
        }
    }
    catch
    { }
```

I want to know that is it possible to do the reference job (<%@ Reference Control="~/ucContents.ascx" %>) at the ''code behind'' dynamically too?

Comment: Do you mean dynamically loading UserControl at run time?

Comment: It is unclear what is being asked here. Please provide more information on what you are trying to achieve so we can help you.

Comment: I will kindly inform you that you should never discard exceptions. You will have no idea what exceptions are thrown within that try/catch block.

Comment: @John Saunders, thanks for kindness, specially about catch :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can load `UserControl` dynamically like the way you posted -

```
try {
    var ucContents = LoadControl("~/ucContents.ascx") as ucContents;    
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(ucContents);
    ucContents.CatID = Request.QueryString["catid"];
}
....
```

Note: you do not need to add `Reference` tag in parent page's aspx if you load dynamically.

Comment: it didn't work. when I delete the Reference, "ucContents" gets inaccessible in (LoadControl("~/ucContents.ascx") as ucContents;).

Comment: I mean you do not need `<%@ Reference Control="~/ucContents.ascx" %>` in ASPX page instead you put it in code behind as `using`.

Comment: By the way, I only see you load the user control, but did not see you add it to PlaceHolder or Panel. Please check my updated answer.